# Sendmail failing to send to some domains

Tags: php, email, sendmail

I've got a small site set up that allows people to send a prewritten email to their representatives, by putting in their own email and their representatives email. 
It's set up using sendmail, and works for sending to gmail, a personal email I have, and various other domains. However, it fails to send to the one domain that I need it to send to. 
I get the following fault

`<www-data@localhost.localdomain>: Sender address rejected: Domain not found`

I've been looking through god knows how many things and I can't seem to figure it out seeing as it's working for everything else.

Hopefully someone can explain it. Cheers!

```
<?php
$field_name = $_POST['cf_name'];
$field_email = $_POST['cf_email'];
$field_recipient = $_POST['cf_recipient'];

$subject = 'Message Regarding Cuts in the Mental Health Budget';

$body_message = 'hello';

$headers = 'From: '.$field_email."\r\n";

$headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$field_email."\r\n";
$headers .= 'Return-Path: '.$field_email;

$mail_status = mail($field_recipient, $subject, $body_message, $headers);

if ($mail_status) { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('Thank you for the message. We hope this will get the TDs in gear.');
        window.location = 'index.html';
    </script>
<?php
}
else { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('Message failed. Please, make sure all boxes have been filled and try again.');
        window.location = 'index.html';
    </script>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: What is the address you give to send with?

Comment: Could you post your sender code?

Comment: @MatthewCliatt added in the code there, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have failed to set "envelope sender" email address used in `MAIL FROM:` command in SMTP sessions.  It can be set by passing `-f` command line option to sendmail. See [additional_parameters in `mail` documentation](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

Comment: So this is what I'm looking for?: 

```mail('nobody@example.com', 'the subject', 'the message', null,
   '-fwebmaster@example.com');```

If so, what's the correct way to apply this when mine is:
 ```$mail_status = mail($field_recipient, $subject, $body_message, $headers);```